# Select last distinct pair

Tags: php, mysql

Ok we have inbox table where we keep messages that users send to each other. Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inbox` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fromid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`toid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`message` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `toid` (`toid`),
KEY `fromid` (`fromid`),
KEY `fromid_2` (`fromid`,`toid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;
```

fromid and toid are id's of the users. We have their id's, times when the message is sent. What we need is a query that would return all messages that are not replied by 'our users' (admins).
Table accounts keeps track of users. To simplify:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`our` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So basically, we need a query that gives us the users WHOSE messages WERE NOT ANSWERED by admins (our users), their count and the date of the last message they sent to ADMIN, ordered from last to oldest.

So far we only have some basic queries, we didn't come up with anything reasonable that I could post.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: From what I see we first need to find last interaction from two DISTINCT users in inbox table... then check & filter only those that were sent TO our users

Comment: Explain the relationship between these two tables. If possible post some sample input output

Comment: Hello, the accounts table has all the users stored. users with value our=1 are admins. In other table (inbox) are messages between users.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT i.* FROM inbox as i 
WHERE (i.toid, i.fromid) NOT IN 
(SELECT i2.fromid, i2.toid FROM inbox as i2 WHERE i2.`time` >= i1.`time` AND i2.id = 1);
```

Another way using `join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i1.* 
FROM inbox as i1 LEFT JOIN inbox as i2 
    ON  i1.toid = 1 AND 
        i1.fromid = i2.toid AND 
        i1.toid = i2.fromid AND 
        i1.`time` <= i2.`time`
WHERE i2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Dylan. i1 is unknown. I tried with >= i.`time` and now the query is locked, takes quite a time, I am guessing that's not what you wanted :-)

Comment: You should ad a JOIN to accounts to check if the sender is an admin.

Comment: ok i tried it. it seems like it's giving me the distinct values, however it doesnt filter our users - i am not sure about this: i1.toid = 1

Comment: you have to join with the accounts table at least to check if the user sending it was an admin

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions presented below: `LEFT JOIN` solution *should* perform better.

**LEFT JOIN solution**

```
SELECT 
 i.fromid, COUNT(*) AS unread, MAX(i.time) AS lastmsg 
FROM inbox AS i 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a 
 ON i.toid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN inbox AS i2 
 ON i.fromid = i2.toid AND i.toid = i2.fromid AND i.time <= i2.time 
WHERE a.our = 1 AND i2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY i.fromid
ORDER BY lastmsg DESC;
```

**NOT IN solution**

```
SELECT 
 i.fromid, COUNT(*) AS unread, MAX(i.time) AS lastmsg
FROM inbox AS i 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON i.toid = a.id 
WHERE a.our = 1 AND 
 (i.toid, i.fromid) 
 NOT IN (SELECT i2.fromid, i2.toid FROM inbox AS i2 WHERE i2.time >= i.time) 
GROUP BY i.fromid
ORDER BY lastmsg DESC;
```

Comment: This is interesting. I tried left join and am getting id's and number of unanswered messages. the only problem I see with this is that they are ordered by id, not by time the last message was sent - is there a way to do it?

Comment: hmm and there is another issue. It seems that this query is filtering users that are not admins TO WHICH the message was sent, not those who have UNANSWERED messages.

Comment: I updated the answer to get an ordered result set base on last unanswered message. As for the last comment, results are actually filtered to consider only messages sent from admin (our = 1) that haven't been answered by the user.

Comment: it should be other way around - consider only messages that are sent from users (our=0) that haven't been answered by admins...

Comment: Please, read again your question: "So basically, we need a query that gives us the users that have unanswered messages from admins (our users) and their count." 
Can you please clarify what data you need to retrieve?

Comment: I am sorry, I am changing that now. We need a list of users that have unanswered messages SENT TO admins. I am sorry, my mistake, I am editing that now.

Comment: Ok, i am testing the first one and it seems that it does something similar to what should be done. So far, the only thing that I think is not correct is the situation when one user posts 3 messages to admin without reply. the count gives the sum of 3, instead 1 (one user), however I am still debating if this is maybe the right way to do it. Maybe this is even better. Can you please elaborate what you did?

Comment: As for `LEFT JOIN` solution, first `JOIN` on `accounts` is needed to check if the user is an admin, instead, second `JOIN` is needed to check if there exists any younger message as answer to the one we are checking. If it exists `i2.id` will contain its id, in the opposite case `i2.id` will be `NULL`. Using `WHERE` clause we are filtering rows whose `i2.id` is `NULL`.